# How to profiling all method in es6 class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to "profiling" all function in class in javascript es6,
for that I created a container and I get from this  container es6 class 
instance wrapped in Proxy class. I think apply method can do that but in fact
when I try to call any method on that object apply method doesn't call
instead of this call the get method on the proxy.

I try to solve that with this code, but it isn't work (infinity loop)

```
get(target, property, receiver)  {
    if(typeof target[property] === 'function') {
        let handler = new FunctionHandler(target, this.className, property);
        handler.beforeCallList = this.beforeCallList;
        handler.afterCallList = this.afterCallList;
        handler.exceptionHandlingList = this.exceptionHandlingList;
        this.count++;

        if(this.count > 5)
        process.exit();

        let fn = target[property];
        return new Proxy(fn, handler);
    }
    return target[property];
}
```

example:

```
class SomeClass {
    someMethod() {
        console.log('SomeClass::someMethod is called');
    }
}

class Logger extends AbstractPostProcessor {

    postProcessAfterInitialization(object, className) {
        let proxy = this.getProxy(object, className);

        proxy.vProxyHandler.beforeCallList.push((data) => {
            console.log(`before call ${data.className}`);
        });

        proxy.vProxyHandler.afterCallList.push((data) => {
            console.log(`after call ${data.className}`);
        });

        proxy.vProxyHandler.exceptionHandlingList.push((data) => {
            console.log(`exception in ${data.className}`);
        });

        return proxy;
    }
}


container.addPostProcessor(Logger);
const someClassObject = container.getObject('SomeClass');

someClassObject.someMethod();
```

result

```
before call SomeClass::someMethod
SomeClass::someMethod is called
after call SomeClass::someMethod
```

https://github.com/ashmna/v1-di/tree/master/src
please see in ProxyHandler.js

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where is this `get` method located, how are you using it? Why do you wrap the `fn` in a proxy again? What is that `FunctionHandler`, what are those lists? Where is there an infinite loop? If you mean a stack overflow, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: here is an all code
https://github.com/ashmna/v1-di/blob/master/src/ProxyHandler.js

Comment: Thanks for the rest of the code, but you still need to explain what you expect the code to do (how it is *supposed* to work), give an example of how you are calling it, and post the exact error that happens.

Comment: let we have SomeClass with someMethod
in general I want to get the object of this class in container
`var obj = container.getObject('SomeClass')`
and when we calling `obj.someMethod()` I want to wtrie logs befor calling and after calling
so for that I want to use Proxy, but in proxy class when we call .someMethod
call the 'get' method in handler that way I return other Proxy for do this logging inside
but it is not working and I cant understand why

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a [MCVE]? "It is not working" doesn't help much